# Clearing previously set value from Selector Editor

Tags: tabulator

New to Tabulator, it's awesome!    Have an issue on a Select editor.  I am populating from a AJAX feed from API/DB.    But my values don't have a "none" option.   So I need to be able to clear the current value to "unselect" it.   Eg set the DB value back to Null / None.

I can't see a way to do that on the Select editor?   What's the most efficient way to clear the current value.

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do, show your [mcve], and tell us what results you get, including any errors or messages. Otherwise, someone who wants to help you will not have any context. In a nutshell: show, don't tell.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a blank entry to your ***values*** object in the ***editorParams*** property of the column definition

```
{title:"Gender", field:"gender", editor:"select", editorParams:{
    values:{
        "":"", //clear cell value
        "male":"Male", 
        "female":"Female",
    }}
},
```